# Gitlab CI Pipeline Deploy to Firebase

Tags: firebase, gitlab-ci

React run build to Firebase hosting

The files get uploaded to Firebase, no page is displayed, the resources get downloaded as they can be seen in the network tab in Dev tools.
When the application is deployed from local environment it work just fine (run on my machine xD)

*firebase.json:*

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "build",
}
```

gitlab-ci.yam

```
image: node:10.11.0 # can be upgraded, depending on your node version used
stages:
    - build
    - deploy
cache:
  paths:
    - ref_project/node_modules/
build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo "Build"
        - cd ref_project
        - npm i
        - CI=false npm run build   
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - ./ref_project/build
            - ./ref_project/firebase.json
            - ./ref_project/.firebaserc
    only:
        - Production
deploy:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - echo "Deploy"
        - cd ref_project
        - npm -g config set user root
        - npm i -g  firebase-tools
        - firebase use ref-project-996a7 --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
        - firebase deploy --only hosting --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN  
    only:
        - Production
```

Comment: I got this issue once. I typed the `firebase.json` file in the wrong property. You can start checking it.